# cannot import name 'imutils' from 'python_imagesearch'

Tags: python, imutils

I wrtie the code as below, but run into a issue about imutils.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cmaster\Desktop\skin_detect\skin.py", line 1, in <module>
    from python_imagesearch import imutils
ImportError: cannot import name 'imutils' from 'python_imagesearch' (C:\Users\cmaster\Desktop\skin_detect\venv\lib\site-packages\python_imagesearch\__init__.py)
```

I already install python-imagesearch and immutils.

Comment: Seems you are using an virtual environment. Did you make sure `imutils` is installed inside this virtual environment? Or, in other words: How did you install `imutils`? Did you activate the virtual environment prior to installation?

Comment: yes, I also checked pip list in my virtual environment. imutils is in there.

Comment: `imutils` appears to be its own separate package.  Why are you trying to import it `from python_imagesearch`?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason would be that the packages are installed outside the virtual environment.

On Windows, venv creates a batch file called activate.bat located in the following directory.

```
\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

To activate the Python virtual environment on Windows, run the script from the directory. Username will be the user’s name logged into the environment.

```
C:\Users\cmaster\Desktop\skin_detect\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

once activated try install the packages again!

Comment: HI I tried. But still don't work.